# How to move to next level/scene in Unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a script that moves from the scene Game2 to scene Game4 if the player object touches another object.

I have written the following code to do that:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NextLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    string strTag;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == strTag)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Game4);
    }
}
```

However when I use that it gives the error:
`Assets/Scripts/General/Collsion.cs(14,36): error CS0103: The name 'Game4' does not exist in the current context`

This is a 3d game.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Game4");
```

There is nothing in your script called `Game4` and [`LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) takes a **string** so it seems to me you are only missing some `"` ;)

---

Btw rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of `==`. Second may silently fail for typos or non-existent tags. `CompareTag` instead throws an exception and is also slightly faster.

Comment: Then either the tag is wrong or the object is a trigger .. or in general: How do you move your objects? I think though that I answered your question regarding the compiler error you got didn't I? ;)